# What does "Think truly, and thy thoughts shall the world's famine feed." mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I'm reading a book, and I came across the following quote by Horatius Bonar.

> Think truly, and thy thoughts shall the world's famine feed.

Could anybody explain what it means?

Comment: The weird thing about the quotation is that it leaves ambiguous whether "thinking truly" feeds the famine (which one might interpret as helping the famine grow and thrive) or feeds people suffering from the famine (and thus, as it were, starves the famine). Not a great quotation, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Think truly, and your thoughts will feed the world's famine.

Answer (score 3):

It probably does not refer to food.  The famine is the dearth of truth.  Seek truth, and you can mitigate the shortage.

Answer (score 1):

It means that your thoughts will provide you with prosperity in order that you may feed others in the world that are less fortunate.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for putting it so crudely before

It means that true (or right or clear) thinking will solve all problems…

It's almost an extension of Newtonian physics: start from true measurements, apply true thought and the outcome will be true.

That the famine won't be solved can be attributed to poor measurement of the initial conditions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a resonate from the law of attraction, we can change the world by our simple thoughts, think truly and true and good things will come your way and vice versa.
I don’t really get the part of about famine, that’s what I was looking for

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/421167)